# What is the right approach to remap native component's attributes

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am new to swift and react-native.

There is a third party native component, called NativeComp which is a subclass of UIView.

and I want to wrap it as react-native component and remap js attributes to native attributes (some rename work)

for example

js

```
 <RNComponent config={enable:true, size:5}/>
```

will lead to native code.

```
component.enable=true
component.size=5
```

- Approach 1

  RNComponent extends NativeComp, and add a new setConfig, configue self in this function.

  It works, but a little weird.
- Approach 2
  write a standlone UIView class ContainerView,  add NativeComp as subview.

  ```
  override init(frame: CoreGraphics.CGRect) {

      self._component = NativeComp(frame: frame);

      super.init(frame: frame);

      self.addSubview(_component);

  }

  override func reactSetFrame(_ frame: CGRect)
  {
      _component.reactSetFrame(frame);
  }
  ```

  it looks much more cleaner than approach 1, but because _component is out of  ContainerView border, the touch event is missing.

  if I write it as

  ```
  override func reactSetFrame(_ frame: CGRect)
  {
      self.reactSetFrame(frame);
      _component.reactSetFrame(frame);
  }
  ```

the program crash `exec bad access` at `self.reactSetFrame(frame);`

I don't quite understand why.

what is right approach to remap js attributes to existing native component?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

self.reactSetFrame(frame) will cause infinite recursive.

after change to super.reactSetFrame, everything works fine.